# Should I use "[FromBody]" values or custom params when responding to an HTTP Post call in a Web API app?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-post, asp.net-web-api-routing, http-post-vars, frombodyattribute

Is POST the right HTTP method/verb to use for telling the server which criteria to use to retrieve data and then save it locally?

I want to send an URL from a client (Windows Forms) app/util to my Web API app to tell it to retrieve data via a Stored Proc, then store the results in a local table. No data is returned to the caller, it's just a notification to do some work.

To prepare for this, I added a new route to WebApiConfig:

```
// Some reports (monthly) only need a begindate, such as "201509"; others need a range 
//  of 2..13 months, such as "2001502" and "201602")
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ReportsApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{unit}/{begindate}/{enddate}",
    defaults: new { enddate = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

In the Controller, this method already existed (was automatically added):

```
// POST: api/PriceCompliance
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
{
}
```

...but I don't know if I want the "[FromBody]" jazz, so I added this:

```
public void Post(String unit, String beginDate, String endDate)
{
    // TODO: Call the corresponding SP (via a Model or directly here?) and store the results in a table.
}
```

Is this the right/better way to do it, or is it preferable to pull the URL args out of "[FromBody]"? In fact, is POST even the right HTTP verb to use for this sort of thing?

Comment: I think POST is right for you. But, I don't really know why you had to create a route for that. What I most do is send the POST along with a json string. Then, you create a DTO with the same fields and you're good to go. No need for FromBody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matter of choosing the right verb for your action is always something debatable. If you look at the item 4.3.3 of **[RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3)**:

> The POST method requests that the target resource **process** the
> representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's
> own specific semantics.  For example, POST is used for the following
> functions (among others):
>
> - Providing a **block of data**, such as the fields entered into an
>   HTML
>   form, to a **data-handling process**;

The keywords in that are highlight in bold. As you can see it fits perfectly your case, where you send a POST request with some **block of data** and some **process** is made by your API.

As matter of **how to handle the parameters** in your POST. You could create a DTO to map your fields: `Unit, BeginDate, EndDate`. Since you are sending your parameters from body, WebAPI will bind the parameters using a `Formatter`. The WebAPI will choose the better formatter to use according to the `content-type header.` In the example I provided, the formatter used will be the JSON.Net (which is the default for JSON)

**PriceComplianceDTO**:

```
public class PriceComplianceDTO
{
    public string Unit { get; set; }

    public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1")]
public class PriceComplianceController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("price")]
    public void Post(PriceComplianceDTO data)
    {
        //Call procedure and process data
    }
}
```

You can also remove the custom route you posted from your WebApiConfig if you decide using the approach above. I just created a new Web API and this is my default route, which is working with the POST:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: It depends on your definition of "data" I reckon; it's not data in the sense of something to store in a table, but args on the URL (the RESTful "address" such as "http://localhost:52194/api/Platypus/gramps/201509"

Comment: Yes. As I said, is very debatable. But I think POST in his case would be the best approach, as the args are (I think) used in his procedure to process data.

Comment: Yes, I'm definitely using POST; my question is: should I use the standard "[FromBody]" approach, or a custom Post method that accepts values corresponding to what's on the URL?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I just updated my answer with an example of a POST without the [FromBody]. Just made a test project :)